# File access using Xamarin.Forms in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, windows-10

I am trying to read the content of a file (D:\Sample.txt) using Xamarin.Forms in UWP platform.
But i am getting an exception "**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Sample.txt' is denied**".

what i tried:

1. Instead of D drive, i pasted the file in the Pictures folder and added the below code.
   string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Pictures), "\Sample.txt");

This didn't work and still the getting the same exception.

2. I enabled "Pictures Library" in Package.appxmanifest. Not sure whether this is the right option.
   But still the same exception prevails.

Can someone help me here.

Comment: add [broadFileSystemAccess to manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: I have added the capabilities  in the manifest file, as mentioned in the link provided. But still the same error occurs.

Comment: in settings app of win10 you have to allow this file access for your app.